# Hibernate prepared statement with dynamic order by

Tags: hibernate, hql, sql-injection

I have a dao layer using Hibernate as ORM and hql for creating queries. Now i need to add dynamic ordering to my queries but i discovered that this is not possible using prepared statements. I don't want to concatenate the ordering column name to the query because it will expose the application to sql injection. Also I cannot switch to Hibernate Criteria because it will require a lot of effort to change all hql queries to Hibernate Criteria. Is there any alternative to concatenate the column name to the query? In case there is no alternative what is a good way to prevent sql injection?

Comment: It is possible to order according to expressions:
 `order by case
  when test1 = something  then 0
  when test2  = something then 1
  else 2
end asc`

Comment: You can dynamically create your HQL and prevent sql injection. I now it is too much effort moving to Criteria but thats must be your solution.